# Get value of clicked raster cell

Tags: qgis, raster, identify

When I open a raster file in QGIS (for example a GeoTiff file), I want to quickly check the value of a clicked raster cell. I found there's an 'identify' tool in the toolbar, but when I click with identify I only see a value (Derived) (Clicked coordinate) Band 1

Is there any tool in QGIS to quickly inspect the value of any clicked raster cell?

Comment: The identify tool should show also the pixel value of each band in the value field. Try with some other images. Don't you get the values from any?

Comment: The identify tool only shows "Band 1" but no value. maybe it's a bug in QGIS 2.4?

Comment: It can be. Put a small sample image for download and write to qgis-users mailing list about the issue. If someone else can reproduce your problem the next step is to make a bug report.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Install the Value Tool plugin. It will display pixel values as you move the pointer around the screen.

Once installed, you will have a `Value Tool` panel docked and you enable the tool by a checkbox:
[image]

Comment: I tried the Value Tool plugin and it does exactly what I need.