# Extracting elevation data from DEM files using QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation, xyz

I know how to generate contour lines from a DEM file once the file is loaded in QGIS and I also know how to open the attribute table for the contour lines which show elevation against IDs. 
Is there a way to look at elevation values against sets of longitude and latitude values in QGIS?
In other words, is there a way to extract and look at XYZ data from a DEM file in QGIS?

Comment: You could export the DEM as text XYZ but it wouldn't load in most text viewers.. what are you trying to do with the Z for an X,Y? Are you trying to script this? How are you going to determine the X,Y to sample with, a point from a feature class, a mouse click..? You could have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120555/get-value-of-clicked-raster-cell and see if that suits your needs.

Comment: I was planning to use a mouse click to get the elevation value

Comment: Using a mouseclick for elevation can be done with the 'identify' tool, which gives you the pixel values for locations you click.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to export elevation attributes from a DEM to a point layer?

To do that, you can use the [Point Sampling Tool](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pointsamplingtool/) plugin to do just that.
Make sure both layers have the same CRS, and run the tool.

[image]

The result is a new point layer with an elevation attribute field

Comment: For now, I only have the DEM file (raster). How do I get a points layer? 
Do I just make a new vector layer and add random points to it?

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions come to mind: In QGIS there's the plugin "Point Sampling Tool", and in GRASS the module: `v.what.rast`.
Both of these extract values from a raster for each feature in a point layer.