# How to get RGB values of clicked point on a WMS raster?

Tags: qgis, raster, wms

I connect to a WMS service: https://resource.sgu.se/service/wms/130/jorddjupsmodell
(More info on them: [here](https://apps.sgu.se/geolagret/GetMetaDataById?id=4b1ce5a5-a403-4a22-b0b3-11c9e53d9c43&showmetadataview)).

I can successfully open and access pixel values:

[image]

After clicking on `Identify Features` (on top, in Attributes Toolbar), then a dark red area, I get `Skattat jorddjup > 50 m`, which is good. I am interested in the RGB value of the clicked pixel though.

How can I get the RGB value of a clicked pixel?

---

This thread: [Get value of clicked raster cell](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120555/get-value-of-clicked-raster-cell) is related but it is about getting pixel value, not color.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the debugging tools in QGIS and find out the GetFeatureInfo requests. One example is here:

https://maps3.sgu.se/geoserver/misc/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&BBOX=55.83588410616951592,12.93924705457158808,55.83605570645990213,12.9395343501247666&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=2&HEIGHT=2&LAYERS=SE.GOV.SGU.MISC.JORDDJUPSMODELL.RASTER_INTERVALL&STYLES=JORDDJUPSMODELL_Intervall_raster&FORMAT=image/png&QUERY_LAYERS=SE.GOV.SGU.MISC.JORDDJUPSMODELL.RASTER_INTERVALL&INFO_FORMAT=text/html&I=0&J=1&FEATURE_COUNT=10

There are couple of things to try:

- change the style into a default style by using an empty style parameter

  `&STYLES=`
- change the info format to some other supported format like

  `&INFO_FORMAT=text/plain`

I tried both changes and the result remained essentially the same. The server returns the soil depth in meters `jorddjup_10x10m = 38.0`.

The server administrator has configured the service to behave that way and user cannot get RGB values. I do not know your use case but maybe you can use some color picker tool and get the RGB values from the image that you see on your screen.

Comment: Empty styles is strictly `styles&`  Ref OGC 06-042 Table 2 — Structure of WMS request using HTTP ~  `http://host[:port]/path[?{name[=value]&}] `

Comment: Maybe, but I can also read in `7.3.3.4 Styles` this: A client may request the default Style using a null value (as in “STYLES=”). And G.1 Example 1: One Server, One Layer, Default Style is using STYLES=. Remainings from older standard versions, maybe.

Comment: Funnily same syntax for WMS 1.1.1 (OGC 01-068r3) Table 2, and WMS 1.1.0 OGC 01-047r2 (Table 1).

Comment: Fortunately there cannot be any WMS server in the World that denies `STYLES=&` and if I read it right the syntax in the tables does accept the usage with an empty string as a value.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that querying the displayed RBG value is note foreseen in QGIS.

A simple workaround, however, is that of using an external (i.e. system-wide) color picker tool.

for example

Under Linux:
https://github.com/Jack12816/colorpicker
or
GPick: `sudo apt install gpick`

Under Windows:
http://instant-eyedropper.com/

for example, with GPick:

[image]